# Truffle migration with TypeScript

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, typescript

I've been able to run truffle tests successfully using TypeScript, but when it comes to migration, I get stuck.

#### 1) My current setup:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",                          
      "module": "commonjs",                    
      "lib": ["es6"],                     
      "allowJs": true,
      "outDir": "build",                          
      "rootDir": "src",
      "strict": true,         
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "types": ["@types/node", "@types/chai", "@types/mocha"],
      "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"],
    },
  }
```

**truffle-config.js**

```
require("ts-node").register({
  files: true,
});
//...
```

#### 2) Migration files:

**1_initial_migration.js**

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

**2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
module.exports = require("./2_deploy_contracts.ts");
```

**2_deploy_contracts.ts**

```
const Fallback = artifacts.require('Fallback');

module.exports = async (
  deployer: Truffle.Deployer,
  network: string,
  accounts: string[]
) => deployer.deploy(Fallback);
```

#### 3) Problem:

I am using an intermediate file `2_deploy_contracts.js` that is calling `2_deploy_contracts.ts`, since Truffle apparently is ignoring the `ts` migration files.

Problem is that some types are not defined when trying to deploy the contracts:

`$ truffle deploy --network development --reset`

Error description:

> migrations/2_deploy_contracts.ts:10:18 - error TS2304: Cannot find
> name 'artifacts'.
>
> 10 const Fallback = artifacts.require('Fallback');
>
> migrations/2_deploy_contracts.ts:13:13 - error TS2503: Cannot find
> namespace 'Truffle'.
>
> 13   deployer: Truffle.Deployer,

Any idea on how to define types for `artifacts` and `Truffle`, or a workaround to run the migration files with TypeScript successfully?

Comment: This does not solve your problem, but there is another newer smart contract development framework called Hardhat that is TypeScript first: https://hardhat.org/guides/typescript.html It has 100% feature parity with Truffle and exceeds Truffle in many areas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MikkoOhtamaa. I've actually heard quite a good feedback about this framework, so will have to give a try.

Comment: @SergiJuanati I want to echo Mikko's suggestion. Hardhat is written in TypeScript, and is meant to be used by TypeScript users. Pro tip: start from my [Solidity template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template), which bundles a lot of useful TypeScript-related utilities, such as TypeChain.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the types using typechain and inject the variable from 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
npx typechain --target=truffle-v5 'build/contracts/*.json'
```

```
module.exports = require("./2_deploy_contracts.ts")(artifacts);
```

2_deploy_contracts.ts

```
module.exports = (artifacts: Truffle.Artifacts) => {
  return async (
    deployer: Truffle.Deployer,
    network: string,
    accounts: string[]
  ) => {
    artifacts.require('Fallback');
    deployer.deploy(Fallback);
  }
}
```